# applications of Procedural Generation outside of game developement

Tags: scalability, implementation, procedural-generation

are there any implementations of procedurally generated code ,in domains outside of game dev and film,
are there any application of the concept as a whole is front-end developement or even system's engineering

as far as i'm aware it's all game dev

Answer (score 0):

The main general-purpose use I can think of off the top of my head is *testing*.

It is sometimes useful to generate large amounts of realistic-ish data as input when testing a system. This could be used as a non-deterministic test to just toss a large amount of random test cases and the expected result to build confidence that the system works beyond your own hand-written test cases.

Generating a large amount of realistic input data at once could also be used to stress-test a system.

A sub-category is *fuzzing*, which is running tests with randomly generated garbage data to see if the program behaves in a well-behaved way even when the input is corrupt or nonsensical.

Of course, if a system deals with certain domains, procedural generation may also be more useful. For instance, a system for performing physics simulations of your designs in various scenarios, say "how does this airplane part handle different types of turbulence". These are more domain-specific cases, however.